# Modifying a list from order A to order B using only push and remove operations

Tags: algorithm, list, transform

Is there any well-known algorithm (or obvious solution) for transforming a list from order A to order B using only `push` and `remove` operations? For instance, from `a b c d` to `b c a d` could be done using the following operations:

```
remove(a)
remove(d)
push(a)
push(d)
```

Or, from `c b a` to `a b` would be

```
remove(c)
remove(b)
push(b)
```

Or, from `a c b` to `a c b d` would be

```
push(d)
```

Here, `push` appends an element to the end of the list, and `remove` removes the element and shifts the subsequent elements so that the list is always in continuous state (no "empty slots"). Additionally there's a condition that at any given moment the list may contain the same element only once. Therefore it seems sound to first do all `remove`s in one bunch, and all `push`es after that. The order of `remove`s obviously doesn't matter, but the order of `push`es does.

A trivial solution would be to first remove all elements and then push the desired elements in the desired order. But since I know that most of the time the transforms will be quite small, equivalent to single `push`es or`remove`s, I want to "reuse" any existing correct order in the list (for instance, transforming `abcdef` to `abcde` would require just one `remove` operation - quite a difference to the alternative (6+5 operations)). So, how to come up with the right (minimum) set of `remove`s and list of `push`es?

Comment: You may want to talk about "push" instead of "add", so as to not make people think that you mean insertions.

Comment: You're right. Editing...

Comment: Or "enqueue" and "dequeue", since the list is obviously a queue. "push" is also used for stacks a lot. But that's nit-picking. =P

Comment: Is it acceptable to build an auxiliary data structure to guide the decision process?  Could that data structure have size O(n) of the original list?

Comment: @ChrisH: Umm, yes, I suppose it's acceptable (in my case at least). How would you do it then?

Comment: @Joonas Pulakka I posted a potential answer.

Comment: What about simple reversals? Going from abcdefgh to acbdefgh is still going to require pushing everything but ac.

Comment: @Joonas: What about the solution posted by Benjamin Manns? That does not work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are going to be removing from anywhere and pushing to the back.

Because you can't insert into the middle of the list, the only way you can minimize the number  of operations is to go through the list linearly and remove any element that is not correct.

i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 -> 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14

1. compare 1

   1. remove 1
2. compare 2
3. compare 3

   1. remove 3
4. compare 4
5. compare 5

   1. remove 5
6. compare 6
7. compare 7
8. compare 8
9. compare 9

   1. remove 9
10. compare 10

    1. remove 10
       (reached end)
11. push 13
12. push 14

If your push wasn't so limited, there would be more efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: +1: This looks about right. It seems we need to find the largest _prefix_ of B, which is a subsequence of A (not LCS), which is what you seem to be doing.

Comment: +1 This looks more efficient and less error-prone than what I wrote. =)

Comment: Thanks. I'll be calling this The Manns Algorithm ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't "well known", but rather something I just thought up.

1. `Remove` all elements from the original that are not in the desired list; add each remove operation to the list of operations.
2. `Add` any elements to working that are missing; add each add operation to the list of operations.
3. Assign to each element of the original list a "order number" which is the position of its analog in the desired list. (see snippet below.)
4. Find the first element (0 at original[1](https://lh3.ggpht.com/_234sVw8l0Y0/S46EPpqG1vI/AAAAAAAADnY/Slas81kuDKA/example1output.PNG)) and the last element in order from there (1 at original[2](https://lh5.ggpht.com/_234sVw8l0Y0/S46EPjLMGyI/AAAAAAAADnc/WhGoYxUHQDU/example2output.PNG)).
5. `Remove` all elements at positions outside of this range and put them in some other temporary list; add each remove operation to the list of operations.
6. Sort the temporary list based on the "order number".
7. `Add` the elements in order from the temporary list; add each add operation to the list of operations.
8. Verify that this newly transformed list matches the desired list.
9. Return the list of operations.

> Ex. from step 2:
>
> 2013 1234
>
> abcd bcad

Because you can only add and remove--not insert elements or add/remove a range--I don't think you can keep the existing order of any in-order sub-segments *other than* the in-order segment from 0. That's why all other elements are removed in step 4. Since you don't have to add those elements immediately after removing (based on your example), I assume it's ok to store them somewhere. So, why not store them in a sortable list and sort based on the assigned "order number" to determine the order of adds?

Unless I've misunderstood your question, you're interested in the order of add/remove operations, so you don't care about actually transforming the list (since you already have the transformed list); you want the steps to create the transformed list. Therefore, each time you add or remove in the algorithm, add the "operation" into a list (queue) of operations (e.g. `operations.Add("remove(a)")`). The algorithm then returns this list of operations.

I wrote a possible implementation in C#. I tested it a little (screen shots below) and it seemed to work. It might also not be the best implementation that someone could write, however.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DetermineTransformOrder<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> original, IEnumerable<T> desired)
{
    // handle the easy case immediately
    if (original.SequenceEqual(desired))
    {
        return new List<string>();
    }

    List<KeyValuePair<int,T>> workingOriginal = new List<KeyValuePair<int,T>>();
    List<T> workingDesired = desired.ToList();
    List<string> operations = new List<string>(); //using Queue<> is ok too

    // load workingOriginal
    foreach(T element in original)
        workingOriginal.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, T>(workingDesired.IndexOf(element), element));

    //1. Remove all elements from the original that are not in the desired list; 
    //   add each remove operation to the list of operations.
    var tempWorking = new List<KeyValuePair<int,T>>(workingOriginal);
    foreach (var element in tempWorking)
    {
        if (!workingDesired.Contains(element.Value))
        {
            workingOriginal.Remove(element);
            operations.Add("remove(" + element.Value.ToString() + ")");
        }
    }

    //2. Add any elements to working that are missing;
    //   add each add operation to the list of operations.
    tempWorking = new List<KeyValuePair<int,T>>(workingOriginal);
    foreach(T element in workingDesired)
    {
        if(!workingOriginal.Exists(x=>x.Value.Equals(element)))
        {
            workingOriginal.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, T>(workingDesired.IndexOf(element), element));
            operations.Add("add("+element+")");
        }
    }

    //3. Assign to each element of the original list a "order number" 
    //   which is the position of its analog in the desired list.
    
    // note: already done above. would have done it here, but
    //       KeyValuePair.Key is read-only.

    //4. Find the first element (0 at original[1]) and the 
    //   last element in order from there (1 at original[2]).
    int indexOfFirstElement = workingOriginal.FindIndex(x => x.Key == 0);
    int indexOfLastElement = indexOfFirstElement;

    // move to index of last in-order element
    for (int i = indexOfLastElement + 1;
         i < workingOriginal.Count &&
         workingOriginal[i - 1].Key + 1 == workingOriginal[i].Key;
         i++, indexOfLastElement++) ;
    
    //5. Remove all elements at positions outside of this range and put them in some
    //   other temporary list; add each remove operation to the list of operations.
    List<KeyValuePair<int, T>> temporary = new List<KeyValuePair<int, T>>();
    var inOrderElements = workingOriginal.GetRange(
                            indexOfFirstElement, 
                            indexOfLastElement - indexOfFirstElement + 1);
    var outOfOrderElements = new List<KeyValuePair<int, T>>(
                                workingOriginal.Except(inOrderElements));

    foreach (var element in outOfOrderElements)
    {
        workingOriginal.Remove(element);
        temporary.Add(element);
        operations.Add("remove(" + element.Value.ToString() + ")");
    }

    //6. Sort the temporary list based on the "order number".
    temporary.Sort((x, y) => { return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key); });

    //7. Add the elements in order from the temporary list; 
    //   add each add operation to the list of operations.
    foreach (var element in temporary)
    {
        workingOriginal.Add(element);
        operations.Add("add(" + element.Value.ToString() + ")");
    }

    //8. Verify that this newly transformed list matches the desired list.
    var newlyTransformed = workingOriginal.ConvertAll<T>(x => { return x.Value; });
    if (!newlyTransformed.SequenceEqual(desired))
    {
        // this should never happen
        throw new StackOverflowException("FAILED");
    }

    //9. Return the list of operations.
    return operations;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No problem. It was interesting to work on (though I stayed up too late =P ).

Answer (score 1):

Brainstorming:

- An arbitrary ordering can be thought of as a sort given the proper comparison function.
- A [Cartesian Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_tree#Application_in_sorting) has the interesting property that it models both the original order  of a list (by in-place traversal) and the sorted order of a list (as a heap).

Perhaps you can use a Cartesian tree to determine the order of operations as follows (edited to fix bugs discovered when working through the example below):

- Call the original list L.
- Construct a Cartesian tree T from L.  This takes O(n) time.
- Construct an empty priority queue Q.
- Assign node N = root of T (this is the smallest item in the list not yet processed).
- Repeat the following steps until Q is empty and N is *null*.

  - Remove all left children of N from L and put them on Q.  Item N is now in position on L.
  - Assign N = right child of N.
  - If N < head of Q: remove N from L and put it on Q.
  - While head of Q <= N or N==*null*: pop Q and push the result on L.

Let's try an example:

I'll use the example from the Wikipedia page for [Cartesian trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_tree):

[image: Cartesian Tree for list 9,3,7,1,8,12,10,20,15,18,5]

At start:

- L = 9,3,7,1,8,12,10,20,15,18,5
- Q = *empty*
- N = 1

First loop:

- Move left children of N to Q:

  - L = 1,8,12,10,20,15,5
  - Q = 3,7,9
- Reassign N to right child: N = 5
- Move N to Q

  - L = 1,8,12,10,20,15
  - Q = 3,5,7,9
- Push items <= N from Q onto L:

  - L = 1,8,12,10,20,15,3,5
  - Q = 7,9

Second loop:

- Move left children of N to Q:

  - L = 1,3,5
  - Q = 7,8,9,10,12,15,20
- Reassign N to right child: N = *null*
- Push remaining items from Q onto L:

  - L = 1,3,5,7,8,9,10,12,15,20

Done.